# How to change the shape of JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

How to change the shape of JFrame in different shape , and also make it interface look alike Mac Windows Frame

Thanks...

Comment: Try the [Quaqua](http://www.randelshofer.ch/quaqua/) look and feel to make your frame look OS X-like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the interface of a Java Swing application look "native" to the operating system it's running on by additing the following lines to either your main method, the init method (if it's an Applet) or to the constructor of your top-level JFrame:

```
try {
  UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
} catch(Exception e) {}
```

**Edit**

UIManager.setLookAndFeel() can throw five different types of exception, documented [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html#setLookAndFeel%28java.lang.String%29) (assuming that you're using Java 6).  How to handle these exceptions is completely up to you - if you ignore them (as in my example, catching all Exceptions and then doing nothing) then your application will use the default Java look and feel.  Maybe this isn't a bad thing?  Only you can decide.

Comment: I gave this an up vote, but please do not post examples in future that ignore exceptions.

Comment: I have edited my answer in response to your comment.  I left the exception caught but not handled just to flag up the fact that exceptions could be thrown by this method, rather than meaning that exceptions could be ignored.  I hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

To make a shaped Window you can use the class com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities. It has a Method called `setWindowShape, it takes two parameters, a shape and and a JFrame. But the class is usually restricted, so it's not a really good solution to use it. I think in the next java edition it will be added as a default class.